# Sorting times with not dates

Tags: java, sorting, date, time

I am trying my hands on this questions:https://www.codeeval.com/browse/214/ and below is my code and ouput:
 **CODE**

```
public class TimeSort implements Comparable<TimeSort>{
   public int hour;
   public int minutes;
   public int seconds;

   public TimeSort(int hour, int minutes, int seconds) {
      this.hour = hour;
      this.minutes = minutes;
      this.seconds = seconds;
  }

  public TimeSort(String str){
    /*DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    final String x = str;
    try {
        Date time = sdf.parse(x);

        //Time time = new Time(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(x).getTime());
        this.hour = time.getHours();
        this.minutes = time.getMinutes();
        this.seconds = time.getSeconds();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    String[] parts = str.split(":");
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

    this.hour = hour;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

public int getHour() {
     return hour;
 } 

public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
    this.minutes = minutes;
}

public int getSeconds() {
    return seconds;
}

public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if(this.getHour() < 10){
        return "0"+this.getHour()+":"+this.getSeconds()+":"+this.getSeconds();
    }

    return this.getHour()+":"+this.getSeconds()+":"+this.getSeconds();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    inputs.add("02:26:31 14:44:45 09:53:27");
    inputs.add("05:33:44 21:25:41");
    inputs.add("02:26:31 14:44:45 09:53:27 02:26:31 01:44:45 19:53:27");

    for (String input : inputs){
        sortTimes(input);
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public int compareTo(TimeSort timeSort) {
    if(this.getHour() > timeSort.getHour()){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(this.getHour() < timeSort.getHour()){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(this.getHour() == timeSort.getHour()) {
        if(this.getMinutes() > timeSort.getMinutes()){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(this.getMinutes() < timeSort.getMinutes()){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if(this.getSeconds() > timeSort.getSeconds()){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

public static void sortTimes(String str){
    List<TimeSort> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] times = str.split(" ");

    for (String time : times){
        list.add(new TimeSort(time));
    }

    System.out.print("Before Sorting: ");
    for (TimeSort t : list){
        System.out.print(t + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.print("After Sorting: ");
    for (TimeSort t : list){
        System.out.print(t + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("==============================================================");
 }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Before Sorting: 02:31:31 14:45:45 09:27:27 
After Sorting: 14:45:45 09:27:27 02:31:31 
==============================================================
Before Sorting: 05:44:44 21:41:41 
After Sorting: 21:41:41 05:44:44 
==============================================================
Before Sorting: 02:31:31 14:45:45 09:27:27 02:31:31 01:45:45 19:27:27 
After Sorting: 19:27:27 14:45:45 09:27:27 02:31:31 02:31:31 01:45:45 
==============================================================
```

The weird thing I am seeing is the times do not print correctly. For example 02:26:31 is print as 02:31:31. And it's the same even if I tried to parse the string time(commented part of the code)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your are parsing dates by hand. That is so error-prone that it's not really us looking at the code any further. Use library code to parse, preferably from [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: @BoristheSpider it looks like this is a coding challenge so libraries are probably discouraged.

Comment: @mdnghtblue I am yet to meet a coding challenge where the use of standard JDK functionality is _dis_-couraged. But if that is the case, the the OP needs to make that clear in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your `toString()` method has a bug:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(this.getHour() < 10){
        return "0"+this.getHour()+":"+this.getSeconds()+":"+this.getSeconds();
    }

    return this.getHour()+":"+this.getSeconds()+":"+this.getSeconds();
}
```

Note that the 2nd field is `getSeconds()` instead of `getMinutes()`.

Comment: Yes that's the problem..thanks you. Gave you an up vote!

Comment: You were quicker ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

Your `toString()`-method does not print the minutes!

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers found the bug in your code.

## java.time

FYI, all of that code in unnecessary. Java 8 and later has the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built-in. Amongst its classes is [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) for representing a time-of-day-only value without a date and without a time zone. This class already knows how to [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo-java.time.LocalTime-) and sort its values and how to [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)/[print](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--) its values. Printing follows standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default.

```
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>();
times.add( LocalTime.parse( "02:26:31" );
times.add( LocalTime.parse( "14:44:45" );
times.add( LocalTime.parse( "09:53:27" );
Collections.sort( times );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( times );
```